# rss feed by linq

Tags: linq, rss

I am trying to extract the rss feed using linq. Thought it would be simple, but its is not returning any nodes. probably i have to go the channel/item node, but don't know how.

```
Dim rssUrl As String = "http://webclip.in/rss.aspx?u=mostliked"
Dim rssDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(rssUrl)
Dim rssResultSet = From node In rssDoc.Descendants("item") _
                   Select New With { _
                   .title = node.Element("title").Value, _
                   .link = node.Element("link").Value, _
                   .description = node.Element("description").Value, _
                   .pubDate = Date.Parse(node.Element("pubdate").Value) _
}

DataGridView1.DataSource = rssResultSet
```

Comment: what error / problem are u facing with the code u have here? 2nd line of ur code should give u the RSS xml in the XDocument object.

Comment: Its working good till the second line. I am not able to access rssDoc.Descendants("item").

Not giving me any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues here... First, you should correct this line:

```
.pubDate = Date.Parse(node.Element("pubDate").Value)
```

The pubDate is a case-sensitive node in XML.  Secondly, your dataSource will never work because LINQ is lazy computation.  You have to use ToList() or a similar method that enumerate your collection.  If you debug within Visual Studio 2010, you'll see that rssResultSet does not have a value because it is only enumerated when your code calls for it.  Replace with this:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = rssResultSet.ToList()
```

My last piece of advice is to set your DataGrid to AutoGenerate it's columns.

Answer (score 0):

the casing on pubdate is wrong.  It should be "pubDate".  otherwise, works fine.